# Spark cluster with two master nodes. Is it possible?

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose we have a `Spark` cluster of 22 nodes. Is it possible to have in the cluster 2 master nodes which would be coordinated for example by `Zookeeper`?

One master node is a standby node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Use following conf options:

> Configuration
>
> In order to enable this recovery mode, you can set SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS in spark-env using this configuration:
>
> System property   Meaning
>
> spark.deploy.recoveryMode     Set to ZOOKEEPER to enable standby Master recovery mode (default: NONE).
>
> spark.deploy.zookeeper.url    The ZooKeeper cluster url (e.g., 192.168.1.100:2181,192.168.1.101:2181).
>
> spark.deploy.zookeeper.dir    The directory in ZooKeeper to store recovery state (default: /spark).

[Standby Masters with ZooKeeper](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#high-availability)